# Scrapy Clusters kafka_monitor.py interrupted

Tags: python, scrapy, cluster-computing, apache-kafka, typeerror

[Scrapy Clusters](http://scrapy-cluster.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/introduction/overview.html) is a great new way to scale large, continuous scrapy projects.  It is setup within a VM and runs with several instances from different tools.

I've built the VM out and installed necessary tools such as Redis, Kafka, and zookeeper.

I'm just stuck on a simple line prior to my first test crawl and I don't know if it's a python issue, installation issue, or what.

When I try

`python kafka_monitor.py run`

I get:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "kafka_monitor.py", line
>   512, in 
>       sys.exit(main())
>   File "kafka_monitor.py", line 497, in main
>       kafka_monitor.run()
>   File "kafka_monitor.py", line 413, in run
>       self._setup_kafka()
>   File "kafka_monitor.py", line 232, in _setup_kafka
>       ret_val = _hidden_setup()
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scutils/method_timer.py", line
>   46, in f2
>       retval = f(*args)
>   File "kafka_monitor.py", line 218, in _hidden_setup 
>   self.kafka_conn = KafkaClient(self.settings['KAFKA_HOSTS'])
>
> TypeError: ____init___() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

The `settings.py` includes:

```
KAFKA_HOSTS = 'localhost:9092'
KAFKA_INCOMING_TOPIC = 'demo.incoming'
KAFKA_GROUP = 'demo-group'
KAFKA_FEED_TIMEOUT = 5
KAFKA_CONN_TIMEOUT = 5
```

And as instructed by the [Quick Start](http://scrapy-cluster.readthedocs.org/en/stable/topics/kafka-monitor/quickstart.html) I made a `localsettings.py` as well

```
# Here, 'scdev' is the host with Kafka, Redis, and Zookeeper
REDIS_HOST = 'scdev'
KAFKA_HOSTS = 'scdev:9092'
ZOOKEEPER_HOSTS = 'scdev:2181'
```

Even if I go into `kafka_monitor.py` and change line 218 (from that intital error traceback above)

From:

```
self.kafka_conn = KafkaClient(self.settings['KAFKA_HOSTS'])
```

To:

```
self.kafka_conn = KafkaClient(self.settings['scdev:9092'])
```

I receive the same error.

Comment: It looks like you have to remove the argument from the `KafkaClient()` call. The medsage is misleading, since `self` is always passed as the first argument. So giving one argument results in two.

Comment: Thanks I did an experiment with that:  with `self.kafka_conn = KafkaClient()` I get `AttributeError: 'KafkaClient' object has no attribute 'ensure_topic_exists'`

Comment: It seems like you have some version incompatibility between kafka_monitor and KafkaClient().  I'd look for the version of KafkaClient with ensure_topic_exists and make sure I have that version installed.

Comment: kafka-python has had a lot of changes in 1.0 version, you probably want to use the same version in scrapy-cluster requirements.txt (0.9.5)

Answer (score 2):

While I am not sure what your environment is, I would highly recommend following the Quickstart guide in the introduction [here](http://scrapy-cluster.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/introduction/quickstart.html) which teaches you how to setup and test your clone of the repo, and even provides a Virtual Machine for you to run and test everything. I can't seem to replicate your issue, but here are some tests I ran against kafka-python (supported) and pykafka (unsupported).

Here, `scdev` is just a virtual machine with Kafka running. Using Python 2.7.10.

**kafka-python 0.9.5 (pinned in requirements.txt):**

```
>>> from kafka import KafkaClient
>>> k = KafkaClient()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
>>> k = KafkaClient('scdev:9092')
>>> k.ensure_topic_exists('test')
>>>
```

Notice that you cannot call the `KafkaClient()` constructor without an argument, so I don't actually know how you got it to work.

**pykafka 2.2.1 (latest on pypi)**

```
>>> from pykafka import KafkaClient
>>> k = KafkaClient()
>>> k.ensure_topic_exists()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'KafkaClient' object has no attribute 'ensure_topic_exists'
>>> k2 = KafkaClient('scdev:9092')
>>>
```

Notice that now works, but we are using a completely different library, and I get the same attribute error. I don't know if you altered the package imports, but I can't seem to find any [reference](https://github.com/istresearch/scrapy-cluster/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=pykafka) to pykafka within the project.

**kafka-python 1.0.1 (latest on pypi)**

```
>>> from kafka import KafkaClient
>>> k = KafkaClient()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/madisonb/.local/share/virtualenvs/sc3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kafka/__init__.py", line 41, in __init__
    super(KafkaClient, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
>>> k = KafkaClient('scdev:9092')
>>> k.ensure_topic_exists('test')
>>>
```

Just to triple check that it works on the latest pypi package.

It is also important to note that the variable `settings` referenced in the question is just a dictionary of elements from your settings files. So calling `self.settings['scdev:9092']` is moot because that key does not exist. Really, `self.settings['KAFKA_HOSTS']` is just a dictionary lookup, which appears to be the string `'scdev:9092'`

EDIT:

I can reproduce the `__init__()` error by using the syntax provided by the kafka_monitor.py with Kafka-Python 1.0.1.

```
>>> from kafka.client import KafkaClient # new syntax for importing KafkaClient
>>> k = KafkaClient()
>>> k.ensure_topic_exists('test')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'KafkaClient' object has no attribute 'ensure_topic_exists'
>>> k2 = KafkaClient('scdev:9092')
Exception AttributeError: "'KafkaClient' object has no attribute '_wake_r'" in <bound method KafkaClient.__del__ of <kafka.client_async.KafkaClient object at 0x102c51d50>> ignored
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
>>>
```

It looks like the versions you have installed do not match the requirements.txt file. This is only going to cause you more problems I suggest to `pip install -r requirements.txt` and see if that fixes the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Success!

@Madison Bahmer thanks for steering me in the right direction.  I want to just clarify how I got it to run.

The first line of actual code (so line 3) in `kafka_monitor.py` reads:

```
from kafka.client import KafkaClient
```

I changed it to:

```
from kafka import KafkaClient
```

This got it to work!

Is this a short-sighted solution? Will something break in the future without:

```
from kafka.client import KafkaClient
```

I don't know but I'll update this in the future if problems specific to this arrise.

Comment: Update: Again thanks @Madison Bahmer if I return to kafka-python 0.9.5 `pip install kafka-python == 0.9.5` then I don't have to modify kafka_monitor.py which is probably the best course of action since that version is the current recomended version in requirements.txt